# Does spark compress on the fly when reading data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Just wondering, when reading no-compress data on HDFS
(raw csv files, not streaming),
if spark is compressing into intermediate state ?

Suppose, for performance reasons, not intermediate compression is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't compress the raw files.

Comment: any reference from the doc ?